# Entity Framework - Navigation Properties issue

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I have a table called "PublicUserNotification" which has the following columns:

1. PublicUserId - mapped to PublicUser.Id
2. FromPublicUserId - mapped to PublicUser.Id

However, the problem starts when I update my edmx file within Visual Studio 2010.

The navigation properties for these two columns are set to "PublicUser" and "PublicUser_1".

This makes using EF on this table confusing as we don't know that PublicUser_1 actually maps to.

Therefore, my question is, does anybody know a way to stop this from happening and instead make EF create "useful" navigation property names for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Open your edmx file and right click in your designer. Select "Model Browser".
In the model browser you can browse to Entity Types and open your table. If you select the navigation property and open the properties window you can change the name of your navigation property.

Comment: the problem with this is that if for some reason a developer deletes the edmx and re-generates it they lose these "specially created" navigation property names. Surely their has to be a way to resolve this?

Comment: Not that I know off... This is in my opinion a disadvantage of code generation. You simply can not change the logic behind it.